# stylus: using iteration to create a set of media queries with mixins

Tags: stylus

I have a set of breakpoints that I've set in Stylus:

`breaks = 320 415 900`

I want to cycle through these and generate a different `media-query` for each, and set a corresponding font via a mixin within each:

i.e. I want something like this to result:

```
@media( max-width: 320px ) { 
    Component_H2_320()
}
@media( max-width: 415px ) { 
    Component_H2_415()
}
@media( max-width: 900px ) { 
    Component_H2_900()
}
```

This is what I have in Stylus:

```
for break in breaks
    @media (max-width: break px) {
         Component_H2_{break}()
    }
```

Not sure why this isn't producing the output that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try using interpolation as listed in the Stylus page `{'.string_' + var} => .string_varcontent`

```
breaks = 300 400 500

component_H2_300()
  width 300px
component_H2_400()
  width 400px
component_H2_500()
  width 500px

for break in breaks
  @media (min-width: break px)
    h1
      {'component_H2_' + break}()
      height break px
```